# Datatables ColumnDefs Access different column data?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I would like to access a property from a different column with datatables.

For example:

```
 columnDefs: [
             {
                "targets": 4,
                "data": "default_price_with_discount",
                "sClass": "text-center",
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<strong>' + data + '</strong>';
                }
            },
            {
                "targets": 5,
                "data": "default_bonus",
                "sClass": "text-center",
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {

                    // how can i acccess here column 4?

                    return '<strong>' + data + '</strong>';

                }
            },
```

Any ideas how to access column 4 from column 5 for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"full" will contain all the column values of row. For example

```
{
"targets": 5,
"data": "default_bonus",
"sClass": "text-center",
"render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
var column4Value = full.default_price_with_discount;
return '<strong>'  + data + '</strong>';
}
},
```